# "ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional" when comparing rows in a pandas dataframe under multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, valueerror

I am trying to compare the rows of a dataframe under multiple conditions and drop the rows under which the conditions are true with the following code:

```
df_new = df_old.drop(np.where(((df_old['A'] == df_old['A'].shift(-1)) & (df_old['B'] == df_old['B'].shift(-1)) & (df_old['C'].isna()))))
```

If the values in columns **A** and **B** of the current row are matching the values in column **A** and **B** of the previous row and the value in column **C** of the current row is nan I want to drop the current row. But the code doesn´t work and I get the following error:

> "ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional"

The Dataframe looks like this:

```
Index      A         B          timestamp            number
0          a600      JH123aas   2020-10-20 13:27:38  35686
1          a600      JH123aas   2020-10-20 13:27:40  nan
2          a350      AV129nas   2020-10-20 13:28:50  nan
3          a158      KU954bas   2020-10-20 13:37:12  nan
4          a158      KU954bas   2020-10-20 13:37:18  15489
```

Any suggestions on how to correct my code or how to prevent the error are appreciated.

Edit: I just realized that I don´t only want to compare the current row with the previous but also with the next row. So the dataframe should look like this in the end:

```
 Index      A         B          timestamp            number
0          a600      JH123aas   2020-10-20 13:27:38  35686
2          a350      AV129nas   2020-10-20 13:28:50  nan
4          a158      KU954bas   2020-10-20 13:37:18  15489
```

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the underlying dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

A sample dataset would have made it easier. However based on your narration, lets try;   `df[~((df['C'].isna())&(df['A'].eq(df['A'].shift(-1)))&(df['B'].eq(df['B'].shift(-1))))]`